# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body - Discord.js Embed

Tags: javascript, discord.js, interaction

Hey i was trying to make a `url` button to my embed when it sent on slashCommand, but when I tried to put the button and use the command I got an error of : ***DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body***

I don't know why is that error showing up and my embed is not working/sending.

Node: v17.7.2

Discord.js: 13.2.0

Here is my command:

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const ee = require('../../config.json');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "Show all the commands",
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {

      let music = [
        "\`play:\` Play a song from YouTube, SoundCloud, & Spotify",
        "\`pause:\` Pause the current playing music.",
        "\`resume:\` Resume the pause music.",
        "\`stop:\` Stop the music.",
        '\`loop:\` Loop the current music or the queqe.',
        '\`autoplay:\` Autoplay music for you.',
        '\`queue:\` Show the music queue.',
        '\`volume:\` Adjust the volume of the music.',
        '\`seek:\` Rewind the current song to the specified position.',
        '\`shuffle:\` Shuffle the music playlist or the queue.',
        '\`nowplaying:\` Show the Current music playing.',
        '\`save:\` Save the current playing music.',
        '\`lyrics:`\ Display the lyrics of the current playing music.',
        '`\filter:` Put a filter to a song.'
      ]
      let info = [
        '\`ping:\` Pings H_M.',
        '\`help:\` Shows all the H_M command lists.',
        '\`links:\` Information about H_M.',
        '`\avatar:\` Shows the avatar of a user.'
      ]
        const helpembed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())
          .setColor(ee.color)
          .setTitle(` | Command list of ${client.user.username}`)
          .setDescription(`** - Music**\n• ${music.join("\n • ")}\n**⚙️ - Information**\n• ${info.join("\n • ")}`)

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
         .addComponents(
           new MessageButton()
           .setLabel('Click here.')
           .setStyle('url')
           .setURL('https://example.com'),
         );
       interaction.followUp({ embeds: [helpembed], components: [row] });
    },
};
```

I tried to follow what it said on this documents: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons
but it seems like I did something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official discord.js guide on buttons => [Buttons | Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#button-styles), there are 5 styles which you can apply to buttons: `PRIMARY` `SECONDARY` `SUCCESS` `DANGER` `LINK`. I assume you want to create a button which leads to somewhere as a link so instead of the style in your button being `url`, change it to `LINK` so that it is something like this => `.setURL('LINK')`

Comment: i did is set the style `url` to `LINK` I must I missed read it something in there lol, thanks Caladan!